# alternate coloring of divs of a repeating html structure via css

Tags: css

```
<article class="tweet-inner"> 
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <div class="tweet">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Coming down! Time for Croation BBQ </p>
        </div>

        <p class="last"> 
            <span class="pull-right">
                <small> Hello this is first text </small>
                <small> Hello this is second text </small>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

I have the following repeating html structure.

As of now, I want to provide alternate rows with different background. The element which I want to color is `class=text`

I do the following in my css -

```
.tweet-inner .tweet .text-wrapper .text:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

This does not work, I also tried -

```
.text:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

This is what works -

```
article.text:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #FF0000;
    }
```

But I want the `.text` to be alternately colored, not the entire article. 
This also does not work.

The fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/LKqvz/. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
article:nth-child(even) .text {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKqvz/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
article:nth-child(even) .text{
  ...
}
```

Because you have multiple `article` elements with a single `.text` DIV (your attempts select the nth `.text` child from `article`)

Answer (score 0):

try  this:

```
    article:nth-child(even) .tweet .text {
           background-color: #FF0000;
      }
```